# how to provide jks file (two way auth) on openssl or curl cmd

Tags: authentication, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, jks

I need to connect to a web service that listens on a port 11902 .

URL of WS = https://apps1618:11902/sng/recon. There is  two way authentication  enabled here. I have been provided two jks file  app_01.jks (with keypass ) and  app_trust_01.jks (along with capass ) . To test that web service listens I want to use openssl or curl or wget cmd to post some data to WS .

I ran openssl cmd =>

```
openssl s_client -connect apps1618:11902

CONNECTED(000000003)

depth=0 /C=PK/Lopac/o=apps/OU=plsop/CN=app_01
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate

verify return :1

depth=0 /C=PK/Lopac/o=apps/OU=plsop/CN=app_01

verify return:1

28693:error:14094412:SSL routines:SSL_READ_BYTES:ssl alert bad certificate:s3_pkt.c:SSL alert number 42

28684:error:1409401E:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:188:
```

I believe above error is coming because it is two way authentication and i have not provided private key and trust cert  through the cmd .

I am not aware  how to provide jks file  through openssl cmd .
I extracted certificate from both jks files in their respective .cer files and ran below curl cmd

```
curl -X POST -d @< path >/mydata --cacert < path >/apps_trust_01.cer https://apps1618:11902

curl(:60) error setting certificate verify location
```

I am unable to use  either of the command to connect to  server.
However  , i checked logs at server side and found that it is getting  my request and  printing  ssl handshake exception (certificate_unknown)

Please provide some pointer that can help me  in understanding how to provide public and  private keys or certificate through any of those commands.

Apologies for my ignorance .

--

Thanks in advance .